# How to click the button in flutter to change the background image

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I am a beginner in flutter, I don’t understand the concept of Widget very well.

I want to set the background image as an unsplash random image, but I want to add a button to request a random image again when I click it, but I am confused about many concepts of Flutter, and I don’t know how to complete this function.

Below is my current code, I don’t know how to change it, please help me, thank you very much!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Welcome to Flutter"),
          ),
          body: BackgroundImgDemo()
        ),
    );
  }
}

class BackgroundImgDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgUrl="https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random";
  const BackgroundImgDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: new NetworkImage(imgUrl),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500.0),
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text("clicke here!"),
            onPressed: () {
              
            },
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you exactly want your code is running perfectaly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a very beginner and I attempted to solve your problem.
My approach was to

1. change your stateless widget to stateful widget
2. Used a NetworkImage variable showImg to pass to the image widget
3. create a function updateUI that will refresh the image to show
4. called updateUI from onPressed function

But this doesn't seem to be working as well. Following the thread to know how to do it

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Welcome to Flutter"),
          ),
          body: BackgroundImgDemo()),
    );
  }
}

class BackgroundImgDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BackgroundImgDemo> createState() => _BackgroundImgDemoState();
}

class _BackgroundImgDemoState extends State<BackgroundImgDemo> {
  final String imgUrl = "https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random";
  NetworkImage showImg = NetworkImage("https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random");

  void updateUI() {
    setState(() {
      showImg = NetworkImage(imgUrl);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: showImg,
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500.0),
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Text("click here!"),
            onPressed: () => updateUI(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! This code solved my problem, and I also learned more about the difference between StatefulWidget and StatelessWidget. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: This approach won't work because what you did wrong was pass the same URL every time on click so even if you setState the NetworkImage won't reload itself as it assumes the image is unchanged and loads from the cache.

Comment: @PriyansuChoudhury: yeah it didn't work. got to learn about cache here.
thanks for the helpful comment :)

Comment: It's okay. Although it doesn't work, I can find the reason why it doesn't work. The most important thing is that I don't know how to use SetState and how to rewrite Widget into StatefulWidget. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to use `StatefulWidget` to make any changes over UI. But here the second issue is image is loading from cache after 1st load being the same URL.

As long you use the same URL within context, images will load from cache.
about the upspash URL you can tweak some value by adding something at the end of URL on button pressed.

Here is the widget

```dart
class MyWidgetsBinding extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
  @override
  ImageCache createImageCache() => MyImageCache();
}

class _BackgroundImgDemoState extends State<BackgroundImgDemo> {
  String imgUrl1 = "https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random";

  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: new NetworkImage(
            "${imgUrl1}$count",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 500.0),
        child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text("clicke here!"),
          onPressed: () async {
            print("clear cache");
            setState(() {
              count++;
            });
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also try `cached_network_image` to maintain cache.

Comment: thanks! This code solved my problem, and I also learned more about the difference between StatefulWidget and StatelessWidget. Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple since the URL never changes flutter assumes that the image is the same and loads it from the cache. To get around this problem all you have to do is provide a different URL every time you click the button. To do this you have to pass a random value to the URL.

```
"https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random" + "#v=${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}"
```

Everything after a # is ignored so it doesn't matter what random value you add but it lets the builder know the URL is changed. You can pass this URL inside a setState to rebuild with the new URL. With this method, you won't have to create any function at all.

**class BackgroundImgDemo**

```
class BackgroundImgDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const BackgroundImgDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BackgroundImgDemoState createState() => _BackgroundImgDemoState();
}

class _BackgroundImgDemoState extends State<BackgroundImgDemo> {
  String imgUrl = "https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: NetworkImage(imgUrl),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 500.0),
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    imgUrl = "https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random"
                        "#v=${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}";
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Click Here!')),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Your answer made me understand the principle, thank you very much for your answer